# Add Variables to an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add variables to an array, what I'm trying to do is to check if there is an error from the view within the controller and the variable will be added to an array here is an example.

```
  $error = array ();
  if (input1 == null)
  {
      $errormessage1 = '*';
      $error[] = $errormessage1;
  }
  if (input2 == null)
  {
      $errormessage2 = '*';
      $error[] = $errormessage2;
  }
  if (input1 != null AND input2 != null)
  {
     //insert to database or something
  }
  else
     $this->load->view("view", $error);
```

The problem is that the values are not being inserted to the array. And the array is not printing anything after I return it to the view.php

Here is an example of my view.php

```
      echo form_label('User Name:', 'input1 ' );
        $data= array(
            'name' => 'input1 ',
            'placeholder' => 'Please Enter User Name',
            'class' => 'input_box'
        );
    echo form_input($data);
    if(isset($errormessage1 ))
        echo $errormessage1 ;
```

Thank you for any help that you can give me.

Comment: `input1` and `input2` are defined as constants in your first script example. Is this a mistype?

Comment: Your errors are stored in `$error` not `$errormessage1` unless I'm mistaken? You are also checking `$errormessage1` and `$errormessage2` with `==` when surely you mean to use a single `=` to set them?

Comment: no, this is just an example, input 1 and input 2 are from the user @isThisJavascript

Comment: Oh i see the mistype @IsThisJavascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to tell the user that username is required. right? then why don't you utilize Codeigniter form_validation library? to display the errors you use form helper method validation_errors()

**Your View**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); 
echo form_label('User Name:', 'input1 ' );
    $data= array(
        'name' => 'input1 ',
        'placeholder' => 'Please Enter User Name',
        'class' => 'input_box'
    );
echo form_input($data);
```

**Your Controller**

```
public function your_method(){
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('input1','Username','required');
//and so on for other user inputs
   if($this->form_validation->run()===TRUE){
      //send to model may be
   }else{
      $this->load->view('view');
  }
}
```